# Get the oldest Timestamp in list Java

Tags: java

Is this correct?

```
ArrayList<Timestamp> timeStampList = new ArrayList<Timestamp>();
timeStampList.add(0, new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis())); 

Thread.sleep(600); 

timeStampList.add(1, new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));

Collections.sort(timeStampList);
Timestamp tempStamp = timeStampList.get(0);
for (Timestamp startstamp : timeStampList)
{
    if (tempStamp != startstamp)
    {
            long diffTime = startstamp.getTime() - tempStamp.getTime();
            diffDays = diffTime / (1000 * 60 * 60);

            if(diffDays > 24)
            {
                System.out.println(diffDays / 24 +"Day" + " "+diffDays % 24 + "hours");
            }
            tempStamp = startstamp;
    }
}
```

I am NOT sure how I can find the oldest timestamp in the array list. Any advice or direct answer is appreciated. Thanks a lot. This current code I think only compares.

**EDIT: So assume I do not use Collection.sort in this context, I know I did apply that when I posted, but lets assume I want to know how to compare and find the oldest timestamp of all in the arrayList via a for-loop.**

Comment: well, you sorted them already, so the lower bound of your list is your oldest.

Comment: I am new to Java, so any advice or help is appreciated. Would the last meaning get(self.size()) be the oldest timestamp of all?

Comment: `Collections.sort` uses ascending ordering, therefore the first element would be the oldest one.

Comment: So the sort() solves it all? Sounds strange to me.

Comment: According to the javadoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)   -- it sorts in Ascending order, so i would think it would be element 0 that you are after.  Here is an example: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaCollections/article.html#collectionssort

Comment: Yes, duh! Index 0 in the ArrayList, now things fell in place.

Comment: @ErikEriksson not really. Your timestamp object is really just a long type internally, with some fancy wrapper to print nice human readable strings (do a print of your System.currentTimeMillis() and see). So the sort algo just has to arrange them in the proper order, ascending per the javadoc (ie, which number is smaller goes first, then so on...)

Comment: So running Collection.sort() and the job is done, at index 0 I'll always have the oldest Timestamp in time (hh:mm:ss) and that's pretty much it, I don't have to work more or make another effort. Sounds way too simple in my head.

Comment: @ErikEriksson sometimes us programmer overthink the simple things ;)  Collections is a great framework, written by one of the best java engineers ever, Josh Bloch.

Comment: It's simple, but it's still too complex and inefficient if you don't need a sorted list of timestamps, but only the oldest one. You should use `Collections.min(timestampList)` instead: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#min%28java.util.Collection%29

Comment: So assume I do not use Collection.sort in this context, I know I did apply that when I posted, but lets assume I want to know how to compare and find the oldest timestamp of all in the arrayList via a for-loop, what would your answer be? I am curious to learn and know that. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @JBNizet would that allow me to retrieve the index of the element in the list?

Comment: Read the javadoc, that's what it's for: no, it only finds the minimum value of the collection (which could not be a list and thus not even have indices).

Comment: @JBNizet That's not good, it's limiting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If, based on your post, you didn't want to sort your data, but instead wanted to just iterate through your entire collection of Timestamp objects and compare that way, you could use the Timestamp's after() method, which establishes whether a Timestamp occurs after the Timestamp provided as the argument of the function.

```
public Timestamp getOldestTimeStamp(ArrayList<Timestamp> timeStampList)
{
    if (timeStampList != null || timeStampList.length() == 0)
    {
        return null;
    }

    Timestamp oldestTimestamp = timeStampList.get(0);

    for (int i = 1; i < timeStampList.length(); i++)
    {
        if (oldestTimeStamp.after(timeStampList.get(i))
        {
            oldestTimeStamp = timeStampList.get(i);
        }
    }

   // oldestTimeStamp is now the oldest Timestamp in the ArrayList

    return oldestTimeStamp;
}
```

I could've sworn I included this in my first edit, but it looks like it didn't take. Everyone in the comments is correct in their wish for you to use the built-in features of the language instead of rolling your own. In this case, you would be far better suited learning to use simple language features like Collections.sort() and Collections.min(), which will invariably be as efficient and typically more so than the kind of code you or I will write, and significantly more succinct than a 12-line method like the one above.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
new ArrayList<>( original ).sort().getLast()
```

## Details

If you do not want to sort the original collection, make a new collection.

```
Collection< Timestamp > original = … ;
List< Timestamp > sorted = new ArrayList<>( original ) ;
```

Then sort. If your objects are [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs//api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html), simply call `List#sort`.

```
sorted.sort() ;
```

Then grab the last one. In Java 21+, use the convenient `getLast` method.

```
Timestamp latest = sorted.getLast() ;
```

---

By the way, never use the `java.sql.Timestamp` class. As part of the terribly flawed legacy date-time classes including `Calendar`, `Date`, etc., you should avoid like the plague.

Instead, use only the *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. In general, use `java.time.Instant`. When exchanging with a database via JDBC, use `java.time.OffsetDateTime`.